# Routing to current_user path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So i have a Bootstrap nav bar on top.

I would like to link_to current_user's edit path, but i always get the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /blog

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
```

That's what im tryin at the moment:

```
<% if current_user %> <--! user logged in? -->
<% @user ||= current_user %> 
<%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_path  %>
<% end %>
```

I dont have this error at a /user/1/ page, but I have it everywhere else.

Also tried this, but didn't help:

```
def edit
  if params[:id]
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  else
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this,

```
<%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_path(current_user)  %>
```

Comment: Had to do stuff, but here we go :)

Answer (score 0):

`edit_user_path` requires a user record to be passed to the path so do the following

```
<% if current_user %> <--! user logged in? -->
  <%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_path(current_user) %>
<% end %>
```